# Match with only one record after using $unwind on the record

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have records as below

```
[
  {
    _id : 1, nm : 1,
    usr:[
         {id : 1, ty : 'team'}, 
         {id : 2, em : 'a'}, 
         {id : 3, em : 'b'}
       ]
  },
  {
    _id : 2, nm : 2,
    usr:[
         {id : 2, em : 'a'}, 
         {id : 3, em : 'b'}
       ]
  },
  {
    _id : 3, nm : 3,
    usr:[
         {id : 1, ty : 'team'}, 
         {id : 3, em : 'b'}
       ]
  },
  {
    _id : 4, nm : 4,
    usr:[ 
         {id : 3, em : 'b'}
       ]
  }
]
```

- I want the count to be `3` when querying with `userAndTeam = [1, 2]`, i.e. if a record has `usr.id as 1 or 2` get those records.
- I want the count to be `2` when querying with `userAndTeam4 = [1, 4]`, i.e. if a record has `usr.id as 1 or 4` get those records.

I have tried using `$unwind`, which made the count to 4 for the first case, as `$unwind` created 3 records for the first record and below query matches with 2 of those records.

The query I have tried:

```
var userAndTeam = [1, 2] //User id and team id. Record should match one of the ids.
var userAndTeam4 = [1, 4]

[{
   $unwind: '$usr'
 },
 {
   $project:{
     'count-2' : {$cond: {
                if: {$in : ['$usr.id',userAndTeam]},
                then: 1,
                else: 0
            }},
      'count-4' : {$cond: {
                if: {$in : ['$usr.id',userAndTeam4]},
                then: 1,
                else: 0
            }}
   }   
 }
```

]

**Output**:

**Expected** for user with id 2 - 'count-2' : 3

**Got** for user with id 2 - 'count-2' : 4

**Expected** for user with id 4 - 'count-4' : 2

**Got** for user with id 4 - 'count-4' : 2

Can someone guide me to solve this problem and to get the expected count?

Comment: You probably need to review "I have records as below" part, as it is not quite clear how you get "A user with id: 4 is part of a team with id: 1" from the provided dataset.

Comment: @AlexBlex please check the question now. I hope my issue and requirement is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$usr"
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "userId": "$usr.id",
            "count-2": {
                $cond: {
                    if: { $in: [ "$usr.id", userAndTeam ] },
                    then: 1,
                    else: 0
                }
            },
            "count-4": {
                $cond: {
                    if: { $in: [ "$usr.id", userAndTeam4] },
                    then: 1,
                    else: 0
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            "count-2": { $max: "$count-2" },
            "count-4": { $max: "$count-4" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            "count-2": { $sum: "$count-2" },
            "count-4": { $sum: "$count-4" }
        }
    }
])
```

What you're missing in your code is that you want to either have `0` or `1` per each `_id` so you need to group by `_id` taking `$max` value of each group which is `0` if none match of `1` if any element matches your array.